# Show specific Products in Table/List view with custom field in WooCommerce Archive Page

Tags: php, html, woocommerce, custom-fields, hook-woocommerce

I have a normal Shop, Category & Single Product Page for normal guest user.
I want to show these products in table or list view with some custom fields which isn't available for normal user. They have their own custom fields which I made by using WooCommerce Product Add-Ons Extension.

I have tried to use plugin to achieve Product Table View but they are not fulfilling my requirement.

I want to add a custom text input field & two quantity field in the customized page; the quantity fields will sum up in Total quantity field column which will be used to multiply the variation price.

I have used **HTML** to achieve this, adding ***/?add-to-cart=171&variation_id=175&attribute_pa_setting=Double-Din*** into **ADD TO CART** but couldn't pass custom field info to cart and email. (I know it's not possible to pass info with HTML)

Can anyone help me please.
Here's a screenshot for what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB0u3.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay solved it on my own.
I don't know if it's the right approach or not.

Here is the code:

```
   <table>

        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Message Box</th>
            <th>Price</th>                
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Submit</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>

    <tbody class="products-main">
        <?php
            $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product', 
            'posts_per_page' => 15, 
            'product_cat' => '', 
            'post__in' => array( 105, 231, 524),
            'orderby' => 'title' );
            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
            global $product; 
        ?>
        <tr class="product-single">

        <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

            <td>
                <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

            </td>

            <td>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type Your Message" />
            </td>

           <td>
                <span class="price">
                    <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                </span>                    
           </td>

            </a>

            <td>
                <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
            </td>

            <td>

                <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $product->id ); ?>" />

                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
                    <?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?>
                </button>

            </td>
        </form>
        </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>


    </tbody>
</table>
```